# How to get data from ng-options if you need to use two model?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have made simple example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLpYJm?editors=101

In this example I need to get field.type and using it with ng-switch.

```
<div ng-app="app">

  <table ng-controller="tableController">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>
          {{item}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="item" ng-options="field.label for field in fields track by field.name" required="required" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div ng-switch on="item.type">
                <div ng-switch-when="BOOLEAN">
                    <input ng-model="item.value" type="checkbox" />
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-default>
                    <input ng-model="item.value" type="text" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>{{selected}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Will you please elaborate us more ?

Comment: what do you mean by two model ? anyway its going to be checkbox or textbox, so its going to be one model only. isn't it @yarikus